# array of const pointers

Tags: c++, vector, constants

I guess this is a very basic question.

when I declare a vector of const pointers, like this:

```
vector<const SomeClass*> vec;
```

Is it a declaration that the pointers are const or the objects that are pointed to by the array element?

thanks

Comment: I think you might find this particular page of the C++ FAQ useful. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, int const \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places the `const` could go:

```
T* p1;                  // non-const pointer, non-const object
T const* p2;            // non-const pointer, const object
T* const p3;            // const pointer, non-const object
T const* const p4;      // const pointer, const object
```

Just read from right-to-left. For this reason, it becomes clearer if you write types as `T const` instead of `const T` (although in my code personally I still prefer `const T`).

You are specifically constructing a vector of pointers to const objects. Note that you could *not* create a vector of const pointers, since a vector requires its elements to be copyable (or, in C++11, at least movable) and a const pointer is neither.

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<const SomeClass*> vec;
```

It's declaring a vector containing *pointers to const objects* of type `SomeClass`.